# How to test if a function inside function called with right parameter

Tags: jestjs

I got this kind of function:

```js
const plus1 = x => x + 1;

const plus2 = x => x + 2;

const returnPlus1OrPlus2 = (number, code) =>
  code === 1 ? plus1(number * 3) : plus2(number);
// if the parameter code is 1 then call function plus1 with param number*3,
// if not then just call function plus2 with param number

export default returnPlus1orPlus2;
```

I have to create a unit testing using jest for that function and I need to test if the function `returnPlus1OrPlus2` calls the right function whether `plus1` or `plus2` based on the parameter code invoked.

```
    test('function returnPlus1OrPlus2 should call function plus1'()=>{
        expect(returnPlus1OrPlus2(2, 1)).toBe(7);
        //expect(function plus 1 was called with 6)
    })
```

*How to mock functions `plus1` and `plus2` and write something like this in test?*

> //expect(function `plus1` was called with **6**)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock or spy on the function(`plus1`, `plus2`), you need to make sure you can access it. Then, use `jest.spyOn` add a spy on the function and assert it is to be called or not. Here is the solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const plus1 = x => x + 1;

const plus2 = x => x + 2;

const returnPlus1OrPlus2 = (number, code) =>
  code === 1 ? exports.plus1(number * 3) : exports.plus2(number);

exports.plus1 = plus1;
exports.plus2 = plus2;
export default returnPlus1OrPlus2;
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
import returnPlus1orPlus2 from "./";
const mymath = require("./");

describe("returnPlus1orPlus2", () => {
  it("should call plus1", () => {
    const plus1Spy = jest.spyOn(mymath, "plus1");
    expect(returnPlus1orPlus2(2, 1)).toBe(7);
    expect(plus1Spy).toBeCalledWith(6);
  });

  it("should call plus2", () => {
    const plus2Spy = jest.spyOn(mymath, "plus2");
    expect(returnPlus1orPlus2(2, 2)).toBe(4);
    expect(plus2Spy).toBeCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59168766/index.spec.js
  returnPlus1orPlus2
    ✓ should call plus1 (5ms)
    ✓ should call plus2 (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.109s, estimated 8s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59168766